# Was there a close call for Voyager 2's extended mission due to lost uplink during the Jupiter encounter?

Tags: trajectory, voyager, jupiter, correction, uplink

In *Uplink-Downlink* (2001), Douglas Mudgway says:  "[The Jupiter radiation environment] . . . resulted in loss of the uplink connection with the [Voyager 2] spacecraft on the day after encounter. By sending repeated commands at various frequencies, the DSN operators were finally able to find a frequency at which the spacecraft receiver would accept the commands, **just in time for the commands needed to fire the thrusters for the trajectory correction maneuver that would enable the spacecraft to make the turn for Saturn.**” - p. 176

But in *Voyager* (2010), Stephen Pyne tells what appears to be a different story: "On the evening of July 9, radio contact ceased, and engineers scrambled to reconnect before  the scheduled course correction. **Happily, the intricate commands had been previously uploaded on July 6**, when contact was clear and before bursts of radiation had upset the temperamental receiver. At closest encounter, Voyager’s thruster rocket began a seventy-six-minute burn calculated to maximize the gravity-assist acceleration.”

Contradiction: Mudgway describes a "just in time" command uplink to fire Voyager 2's thrusters, while Pyne says the burn had been pre-programmed days earlier. Yet Pyne also says that engineers "scrambled to reconnect before the scheduled course correction."  Why scramble, if the maneuver was pre-programmed?

Were there perhaps *two* burns, one at closest approach and one "the day after encounter" (Mudgway) - the first pre-programmed, the second requiring new uplinked commands?

Also: If some form of the "just in time" story is true, what time margin, exactly, does "just in time" refer to?

My thanks in advance for any sources that clarify the timeline of events.

Comment: I, personally, think that the "just in time" story makes no sense, if you consider the distance between Earth-Jupiter there should already be a  ~5 seconds time delay between sending a command a observing the result, so there is no way you can command a burn directly. Therefore, everything should be already pre-programmed. For the other scenario, my humble guess would be if the radiation is too high for electrical components to resist, some part of the circuit may be damaged, then engineers might wanted to see everything is OK during mission, not because they could do something.

Comment: But after Pioneer 10-11 & Voyager 1, I don't think that NASA just sent out a spacecraft into space without radiation shields. As confirmed by Robert J. Parks at https://www.nytimes.com/1979/03/06/archives/a-hostile-jupiter-yields-surprises-a-hostile-jupiter-yields-some.html

Comment: @LadyBeGood The delay was somewhat larger than 5 seconds. ;) The distance from Earth to Voyager 2 at its closest approach to Jupiter was ~931.9 million km, which is ~3108 light-seconds. https://i.stack.imgur.com/94es4.png https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&EPHEM_TYPE=V&CSV_FORMAT=YES&VEC_TABLE=6&COMMAND=-32&CENTER=%40399&START_TIME=%271979-Jul-9+20%3A00+UT%27&STOP_TIME=%271979-Jul-9+22%3A00%27&STEP_SIZE=15m

Comment: Aah yea, it should be around 3000 ( missed km with million km) seconds which makes it impossible to control completely manual, thanks for correction

Comment: @LadyBeGood "But after Pioneer 10-11 & Voyager 1" - there can't be any causality there, Voyager 1 launched only after Voyager 2.

Comment: Perhaps there were 2 burns: first a preprogrammed burn during closest approach, then a course correction the day after whose character depended on the results of the slingshot maneuver.  If the 2nd burn had to be calculated based on fresh navigational measurements, it would have require freshly uploaded commands and Mudgway's story could make sense.  (NB: He was a manager in the Deep Space Network and his book was published by NASA, so I'm reluctant to dismiss what he says.)  But it would be great to identify a primary source describing the incident, and to know how close the call really was.

Comment: @asdfex by the time the Voyagers got to Jupiter, Voyager 1 had overtaken Voyager 2, so it arrived at Jupiter first (March 5, V2 arrived July 9)